# Transconductance and voltage gain of LT1534

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, ota

In the datasheet of the [LT1534](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1534fa.pdf) it says the error amplifier transconductance is 1.5 mS (typ.) and the error amplifier voltage gain is 250 V/V (typ.):

[image]

But on page 11 it says the output impedance of the error amplifier is about 400 kΩ:

[image]

I would have calculated the voltage gain as G = g<sub>m</sub> x R<sub>OUT</sub> = 1.5 mS x 400 kΩ = 600 V/V. Can this calculated voltage gain be reconciled with the gain given in the datasheet (250 V/V)?

Answer (score 1):

I have got an answer from Analog. They said it is the Electrical Characteristics, which are measured, that I should trust rather than the text section in the datasheet. So the error amplifier voltage gain really is 250 V/V and its transconductance is 1.5 mS, leading to an Rout of about 167 kOhm. I even made some measurements which confirm Rout should be in the ballpark of 167 kOhm.